# Не могу найти ошибку при вычислении факториала

Tags: c++, visual-studio, математика, ряды, факториал

Моя задача написать код для вычисления данного выражения на c++
[image: Задача]

Написал такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    double P = 1.0;
    double factorial, z, Q;
    int n;
    printf("Введите число:\n");
    scanf_s("%i", &n);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++){    
        factorial = 1;
        int j = 1;
        while (j <= i){
            factorial *= j;
            j++;
        }
        z = (double)(i + 2);
        Q = factorial / z;
        P = P * Q;
    }
    printf("\nРезультат: Р=%e=%0.3f", P, P);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Проверяю работу, ввожу 4
Терминал выдаёт: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Сайт-калькулятор](https://ru.symbolab.com/solver/series-calculator/%5Csum_%7Bi%3D2%7D%5E%7B4%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(i-1%5Cright)!%7D%7Bi%2B2%7D?or=input)
Даёт ответ[image: введите сюда описание изображения] = 1,65

Подозреваю, что неправильно написал что-то в while.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Стоп-стоп-стоп... Задание — считать произведение, а проверяете вы, считая онлайн-калькулятором *сумму*? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Ошибка при вычислении факториала -- он должен вычисляться для `i - 1`, для n=4: `P = 1/4 * 2/5 * 6/6= 1/10` К тому же вложенный цикл для вычисления факториала не нужен, можно использовать значение с предыдущего шага.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стоп-стоп-стоп... Задание — посчитать **произведение**, а проверяете вы, считая онлайн-калькулятором **сумму**? Я правильно понял? :)

Впрочем, ваш код и в самом деле дает неверные результаты.
Потому что вы считаете не `(i-1)!`, а `i!` — посмотрите сами, пройдите цикл карандашом на бумажке...

Только вот считать каждый раз факториал с нуля нет смысла. Я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Введите число: ";
    cin >> n;

    double P = 1.0;
    for(long long i = 2, f = 1; i <= n; f *= i++) P *= f/(i+2.);
    cout << P << endl;
}
```

`cin`, `cout` — все же у вас С++, а не С.

P.S. Кстати, для 4 [правильный ответ](https://ideone.com/e6TDIG) — 0.1.